# Import tweets into wordpress including their twitpics

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I've got a very interesting problem, I installed Wordpress and want to feed it with Twitter tweets but taking care that this tweets are stored and treated like normal worpdress posts.
I achieve this thanks to a plugin named Tweeter Import but now I also want the images and links that are attached to the tweets and I only get those weird URLs that link to either an image or an external URL (anyone who uses TweetDeck knows what I mean).
My question is: How can I retrieve this attached images and URLs and show them up if they are simple links or store the image as part of the post in the DB?
I'll try to explain myself better: After storing the tweet content like title or text, I need to retrieve the images, if there are any, and store them like any other image I could put into a post I would write from Wordpress's admin panel.
The same way distinguish between image links and normal external links, which I want to show like exactly this.
Hope there is someone who brings me the answer or any hint!!!!
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is look at some of the premium autoblogging plugins like Autoblogged or Topic Storm.  They are not free and unfortunately have no trial version but one of those should be able to pull the image in.  Contact the sales team or developer from the sites...they should be able to confirm the functionality.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer, I gonna review those plugins, cheers!